# Type Error undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typeerror, server-sent-events

I am trying to create a Server Sent Event class that will observe other component and send information to them but I've got an error when I try to subscribe to my observable.

this is my Server Sent Event class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerSentEvent implements OnInit{
  public observable : Observable<any>;
  ngOnInit(){
    var errorCount = 0;
    this.observable = Observable.create(observer => {
      var eventSource = new EventSource(filterUrl);
      eventSource.onmessage = (event: any)=>{
        console.log("received val: " + JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data).payload).value);
        observer.next(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data).payload).value);
      }
      eventSource.onerror=(error: any)=>{
        errorCount++;
        if(error.targer.readyState === 0 && errorCount > 5){
          eventSource.close();
          observer.error();
        }
      }
      return() => {
        eventSource.close();
      };
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my lightControler class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[ServerSentEvent]
})
export class LightControler implements OnInit{
  connected : boolean;
  light : boolean;
  public button = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("check-toggle"));
  public slider = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("light-slide"));
  public slid = (<HTMLProgressElement>document.getElementById("light-bar"));

  public constructor(
    private http : HttpClient,
    private serverSentEvent: ServerSentEvent){
    this.serverSentEvent.observable.subscribe(
      {
        next: val =>{
          console.log("light val: "+ val);
          this.slid.value = val;
          if (val >= 1){
            this.light = true;
            this.button.checked = true;
          }
          else{
            this.light = false;
            this.button.checked = false;
          }
        },
        error: error =>{
          setTimeout(()=> serverSentEvent.ngOnInit(), 1000);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

the error is on the this.serverSentEvent.observable.subscribe()

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.serverSentEvent.observable.subscribe')

Does anyone know how to fix that or what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

the ngOnInit of the ServerSentEvent wasn't launch when the constructor of the lightControler was so i tried to subscribe to an observable that wasn't existing.

I need to call the serverSentEvent.ngOnInit() before subscribing to the observable.

Comment: What is the output from this console log?: `console.log("received val: " + JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data).payload).value);`

Comment: this return the value that openhab server send me for a light its a number from 0 to 100.

Comment: Hm, then at what point/line in the onNext do you get this error from the subscription?

Comment: i get the error before that the error is : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.serverSentEvent.observable.subscribe')

Comment: Then it's likely an issue with how your components are being loaded. the observable is being created in the ngOnInit lifecycle of the ServerSentEvent class, and when the LightController class is constructing the subscription if the ngOnInit hasn't started then the observable doesn't exist. Seems like you tried to account for that on the onError event of the subscription to wait but the onError won't fire if you can't subscribe to the observable in the first place.

Comment: But isn' t the ngOnInit of the ServerSentEvent starting  when i create the private object serverSentEvent in the constructor of the LightControler?

Comment: Not necessarily. ngOnInit only fires when the compiler has defined & constructed the class it is in. Furthermore, I noticed you have an ngOnInit lifecycle as part of an @Injectable. Injectables (services) don't have lifecycle hooks. Try removing the ngOnInit from your Injectable entirely and just make the observable a class variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an object to the subscribe function instead of a function. Try changing your code like this:

```
this.serverSentEvent.observable.subscribe(
  val => {
      console.log("light val: "+ val);
      this.slid.value = val;
      if (val >= 1){
        this.light = true;
        this.button.checked = true;
      }
      else{
        this.light = false;
        this.button.checked = false;
      }
    },
    error => {
      setTimeout(()=> serverSentEvent.ngOnInit(), 1000);
    });
```